# IllegalAccessError in springApplication in maven simple project

Tags: java, spring, maven

I'm trying to run a simple application in maven after adding the **Spring Jars 3.2.5.RELEASE**, my Eclipse is 3.8.3.RELEASE, and I'm getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.loadFactoryNames(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)Ljava/util/List; from class org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:402)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:394)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.initialize(SpringApplication.java:261)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>(SpringApplication.java:237)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175)
at Main.main(Main.java:8)
```

My main:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Main {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);

   }

}
```

My pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0     http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>io.javabrains.springbootquickstart</groupId>
  <artifactId>course-api</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>TrySpring</name>

<parent>

  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>

</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>


</project>
```

I've also tried using STS but I get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using such an old version of Spring with the newest version of spring boot?  I would suspect the issue is a class path collision where the 3.2.5 release is getting referenced instead of the appropriate 4.x.x jar for a newer spring boot application.

When you use the starter poms like you are, all the required jars (a ton of excess actually) get included for your use, you shouldn't need to specifically include any spring jars on your path.

Comment: I thought the jars was necessary as I saw it in some video, but I removed them and it worked.
thanks.